# relative homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I study relative homotopy groups and I have a question:
Let $A\subseteq X$ (not necessarily CW complex) and $\pi_{n}(X,A)$. Is it always possible to find a pointed space Y for which $\pi_{n}(X,A)=\pi_{n-1}(Y)$ for all $n\geq 1$ ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: by "=" I mean isomorphic

Comment: as it is written the answer is "yes" because, given "any" group $G$ you find $Y$ such that $\pi_{n-1}(Y)=G$. Here " " means "up to natural restrictions". you probably want something where X and Y are related somehow, don't you?

Comment: No X,Y are not necessarily related. I ask generally. How each group is realised as $\pi_{n}$ ? Is it also possible for n=1?

Comment: higher ($n\geq 2$) homotopy groups are abelian so there are "natural" restrictions

Comment: For $n=1$ the $\pi_1$ is the space of connected components of maps $[0,1]\to X$, so it is the $\pi_0$ of some space

Comment: is the space of maps

Comment: This is related to general constructions like Cayley graph (or complex), the presentation complex and the Eilemberg-MacLane spaces. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_complex

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph

Answer (score 2):

It seems that  you are thinking of turning the inclusion $i:A \to X$ (of pointed spaces) into a fibration $p:E_i \to X$ and looking at the fibre (or fiber)  $F_i$ of $p$ over the base point $x$ of $X$. Then $\pi_n(X,A,x) \cong \pi_{n-1}(F_i,y)$. This idea is important for your study of  relative   homotopy groups.

There is a wikipedia entry on [homotopy fiber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_fiber) though it is slightly inaccurate since it refers to spaces rather than spaces with base point.